# Bugzilla - workflow customization

Tags: workflow, customization, bugzilla

I want to change the Bugzilla workflow so that a user won't be able to close a bug unless the bug has gone through some phases (e.g. ASSIGNED, IN_PROGRESS, etc).

How do I change Bugzilla in order to create my own work flow?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [changing the workflow from within bugzilla itself](http://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/administering/workflow.html)?

(Edit: updated URL for 5.0)

Comment: Note that this feature was introduced in bugzilla 3.2: http://www.bugzilla.org/releases/3.2/new-features.html

Comment: For 5.x:  http://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/administering/workflow.html

Answer (score 2):

If your primary concern is permissions, you'll want to check out check_can_change_field in Bugzilla/Bug.pm.

Answer (score 1):

There's only so much customization you can do in editworkflow.cgi, because RESOLVED much be reachable from any other status (because when it is marked as a duplicate, for instance, it becomes RESOLVED).  The workflow itself doesn't consider the history of the bug.

If you really wanted to enforce this sort of business logic, you should start diving into process_bug.cgi.  If someone want to set the status to FOO but it needs to have been in status BAR before, you could check the bug's history in bugs_activity.

But that's a lot of work, and you're likely to have special cases, more rules, more special cases, etc.

I think you would be better off identifying bugs that didn't go through the proper workflow after the fact.  When you identify such a bug, you would reopen them or put them into whatever status.

You would do this by examining bugs_activity to see what values of bug_status have been added/removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in two steps:

1. Go to editvalues.cgi?field=bug_status and add/delete/rename the names of the different status.
2. Go to the editworkflow.cgi and customize the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create first a status. Type *"closed"* to Status type (Administration/Field values/Status (This value will not be used (for example the name "Do not use"))
2. Go to Admininistration/Parameters/Bug change policies. Choose your new status
3. Go to Edit workflow (Admininistration/Bug Status Workflow). You can now uncheck RESOLVED

It is a way of doing